# Are arguments for GraphQL automatically provided?

Tags: graphql

I was wondering if there was a GraphQL tool or command that provides all the variables available for consumption in a query or mutation.

For example, if you know the query name, you'd be provided a full list of GraphQL query arguments. Something like:

```
    {
        person(){
            nodes{
            firstName,
            lastName,
            birthDate,
            arg1,
            arg2,
            ...,
            argn
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you'd have a list provided somehow. Does this exist?

Comment: "graphql introspection"

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. Thanks.